# Concatenating the positional encoding

Tags: attention, word-embedding, positional-encoding

As per "Attention is all you need" etc., positional encoding is added to the embedded word vector input. My knee-jerk reaction is that this would muddle the "signal" of the word vector. Since word order is not preserved, this additive noise, for instance, could make a word look like a different word (in a different position): $w_a + p_a = x = w_b + p_b$.

Is performance (from shorter input dimension) the main reason to add the positional information versus concatenating, or is adding theoretically sound?

**Edit:** I think a source of confusion in all of this is the assumption of whether the model adopts a pre-trained word embedder, like Word2Vec, or trains their embedder from scratch. Adding positional encoding to a pre-trained embedder might throw off the attention dot product?

Comment: You may want to do some calculations to understand just how little the positional embeddings move the word embeddings to see if that helps you intuitively.

Comment: Range from PE would be [-1,1] which I imagine is also the word embed range, no?

Comment: I'd say elegance is the main reason in conjunction with the evidence that the addition works well: If you'd concatenate you'd need another dimensionality reducing transformation to make subsequent residual connections work. Also check [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/35990/52211) related question, I like the orthogonality argument in the [first](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/43213/52211) answer, second answer is my own attempt of explanation ;)

Comment: How is this question different from [Why are embeddings added, not concatenated?"](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/35990/61494) that @Chillston linked above?